# Refreshing the tab on Page Select

Tags: android, android-viewpager

My android application has 3 swipe tabs. all 3 tabs are attached to the view pager. I want to refresh the corresponding tab on its selection. How do I do it?

Comment: You can add the code you want to update in `onResume()` method.

Comment: setOnPageChangelister()

Comment: activesince93, the signal does not go to onResume onPageSelected

Comment: tiny sunlight I am using setOnPageListener but there should be more signal needed to refresh.